# Spark-shell is not invoked from other directories

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu-16.04

I can access spark in this directory /home/sharan/spark-lab/spark but i cannot access it elsewhere.
I mentioned the path in .bashrc file also, still I am getting **spark-shell: command not found**

```
#Export Spark
export SPARK_HOME=/home/sharan/spark-lab/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
```

Comment: Did you source the .bashrc on the shell ?

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya  In ~/.profile file `if [ -s ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc;
fi

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
 . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/home/sharan:$PATH"`

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya: In ~/.bash_profile `source ~/.profile
export SPARK_HOME=/home/sharan/spark-lab/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin` still it is not working